# Why float is more precise than it ought to be?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, floating-point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    long double pival = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899L;
    float pival_float = pival;
    printf("%1.80f\n", pival_float);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I got on gcc is :

```
3.14159274101257324218750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The float uses 23 bits mantisa. So the maximum fraction that can be represented is 2^23 = 8388608 = 7 decimal digits of precision.

But the above output shows 23 decimal digits of precision (**3.14159274101257324218750**). I expected it print **3.1415927**000000000000....)

What did I miss to understand ?

Comment: Floats are *binary*. They don't *have* "decimal digits of precision" in exact way.

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: actually float has 24 bits of significant (23 bits of mantissa + 1 hidden bit)

Comment: Try `printf("%a\n", pival_float)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only got 7 digits of precision. Pi is

**3.141592**6535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209...

But the output you got from printing your float approximation to Pi was

**3.141592**74101257324218750000...

As you can see the values diverge starting from the 7th digit after the decimal point.

If you ask `printf()` for 80 digits after the decimal place, it will print out that many digits of the decimal representation of the binary value stored in the float, even if that many digits is far more than the precision allowed by the float representation.

Answer (score 4):

A binary floating-point value can't represent 3.1415927 exactly (since that's not an exact binary fraction). The nearest value that it *can* represent is 3.1415927410125732421875, so that's the actual value of your `pival_float`. When you print `pival_float` with eighty digits, you see its exact value, plus a bunch of zeroes for good measure.

Answer (score 4):

The closest `float` value to pi has binary encoding...

```
0 10000000 10010010000111111011011
```

...in which I've inserted spaces between the sign, exponent and mantissa.  The exponent is biased, so the bits above encode a multiplier of 2^1 == 2, and the mantissa encodes a fraction above 1, with the first bit being worth a half, and each bit thereafter being worth half as much as the bit before.

Therefore, the mantissa bits above are worth:

```
1 x 0.5
0 x 0.25
0 x 0.125
1 x 0.0625
0 x 0.03125
0 x 0.015625
1 x 0.0078125
0 x 0.00390625
0 x 0.001953125
0 x 0.0009765625
0 x 0.00048828125
1 x 0.000244140625
1 x 0.0001220703125
1 x 0.00006103515625
1 x 0.000030517578125
1 x 0.0000152587890625
1 x 0.00000762939453125
0 x 0.000003814697265625
1 x 0.0000019073486328125
1 x 0.00000095367431640625
0 x 0.000000476837158203125
1 x 0.0000002384185791015625
1 x 0.00000011920928955078125
```

So, the least significant bit after multiplying by the exponent-encoded value "2" is worth...

```
0.000 000 238 418 579 101 562 5
```

I added spaces to make it easier to count that the last non-0 digit is in the ***22nd*** decimal place.

The value the question says `printf()` displayed appears below alongside the contribution of the least significant bit in the mantissa:

```
3.14159274101257324218750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0.0000002384185791015625
```

Clearly the least significant digits line up properly.  If you added up all the mantissa contributions above, added the implicit 1, then multiplied by 2, you'd get the *exact* value `printf` displayed.  That explains how the `float` value is *precisely* (in the mathematical sense of zero randomness) the value shown by `printf`, but the comparison below against pi shows only the first 6 decimal places are *accurate* given the particular value we want it to store.

```
3.14159274101257324218750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899
        ^
```

In computing, it's common to refer to the precision of floating point types when we're actually interested in the *accuracy* we can rely on.  I suppose you could argue that while taken in isolation the precision of floats and doubles is infinite, the rounding necessary when using them to approximate numbers that they can't encode perfectly is for most practical purposes random, and in that sense they offer finite significant digits of precision at encoding such numbers.

So, `printf` isn't wrong to display so many digits; some application might be using a `float` to encode that *exact* number (almost certainly because the nature of the app's calculations involve sums of 1/2^n values), but that'd be the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 2):

Carrying on from Tony's answer, one way to prove this limitation on decimal precision to yourself in a practical way is simply to declare `pi` to as many decimals points as you like while assigning the value to a `float`. Then look at how it is stored in memory.

What you find, is no matter how many decimal points you give it, the `32-bit` value in memory will always be the equivalent of the `unsigned` value `1078530011` or `01000000010010010000111111011011` in binary. That is due, as others explained, to the **IEEE-754 Single Precision Floating Point Format** Below is a simple bit of code that will allow you to prove to yourself that this limitation means `pi`, as a float, is limited to six decimal precision:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined (__LP64__) || defined (_LP64)
# define BUILD_64   1
#endif

#ifdef BUILD_64
# define BITS_PER_LONG 64
#else
# define BITS_PER_LONG 32
#endif

char *binpad (unsigned long n, size_t sz);

int main (void) {

    float fPi = 3.1415926535897932384626433;

    printf ("\n fPi : %f,   in memory : %s    unsigned : %u\n\n",
            fPi, binpad (*(unsigned*)&fPi, 32), *(unsigned*)&fPi);

    return 0;
}

char *binpad (unsigned long n, size_t sz) 
{
    static char s[BITS_PER_LONG + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + BITS_PER_LONG;
    register size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        *(--p) = (n>>i & 1) ? '1' : '0';

    return p;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/ieee754_pi

 fPi : 3.141593,   in memory : 01000000010010010000111111011011    unsigned : 1078530011
```